# Maps.me working with own OSM server?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, server, maps.me

I have my own OSM server which is updating every few minutes in shyncrony with OSM original servers, using a PostGIS database and rendering with renderd.

I can see offline downloaded maps through an Apache server (using OpenLayers).

I would like to use this database as a repository for Maps.me, but, the format of these maps is `.mwm`, while mines are stored in database, and, the downloaded raw data maps are `.osm.pbf` files.

Is PostGIS database useless for this purpose?
Or do I have to convert the `.osm.pbf` files into `.mwm` format files?

Answer (score -1):

If u want to upload data in`.mvm` or other format, use this manual [learnosm.org/en/osm-data/geofabrik-and-hot-export/](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/geofabrik-and-hot-export/). But it ***not sync*** data from OSM.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! As a new user please take the [tour]. A good answer should be self-contained, and include all the steps and details required.  Links can change or disappear over time, and so link-only answers should be expanded and use the link as reference only.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation and process to your answer.